# Repeating the subject rather than using perfect infinitive in passive sentences

Tags: passive-voice, perfect-infinitive

Is it allowed to rewrite [repeating the subject] this passive sentence:

> She is reported to have died in a plane crash.

into this:

> She is reported that she has died in a plane crash.

I'm in doubt because the first passive sentence has the construction:

> **subject + passive verb + infinitive**

and I don't know whether the second sentence is still acceptable grammatically because it uses the same subject twice and makes it look ineffective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your second sentence is not grammatical. It would be permissible to say "*It* is reported that she has died in a plane crash." In that case, the "it" would refer to the entire clause after "that" -- i.e. the fact (that she has died in a plane crash) is reported.